# Changing the colour of a logo while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have setup a page that when scrolling down, the colour of the menu changes to make up for the backgrounds - so on the white background the text would be black and vice versa.

I would like to change the text to a logo so that on the white background the logo would be black; using the image LOGOBLACK.png and vice versa with LOGOWHITE.png.

Here is the menu in index.html:

```
<nav id="menu" class="hidden">
<ul>
    <li class="go-home">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/LOGOBLACK.png"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the javascript code that I was using before:

```
function updateMenuColor() {
var t = Math.max(window.scrollY, 0) + 50,
    e = t - y;
setScrollUp(0 >= e), y = t;
for (var i = document.getElementsByTagName("section"), n = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(), s = 0; s < i.length; s++) {
    var a = i[s],
        o = a.getBoundingClientRect(),
        r = o.top - n.top,
        l = o.bottom - n.top;
    if (y > r && l > y) {
        var c = a.classList.contains("white");
        c && !$menuIsWhite ? (switchMenuToWhite(), $menuIsWhite = !0) : !c && $menuIsWhite && (switchMenuToBlack(), $menuIsWhite = !1);
        var h = a.classList.contains("text");
        h && !$menuIsFaded ? (fadeMenuIn(), $menuIsFaded = !0) : !h && $menuIsFaded && (fadeMenuOut(), $menuIsFaded = !1)
    }
}
}

function switchMenuToWhite() {
    document.body.classList.add("white")
}

function switchMenuToBlack() {
    document.body.classList.remove("white")
}
```

What I am failing to understand is how to substitute the text for a logo.  Any type of comment is always appreciated.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous solution worked by adding and removing a class on body. There is no pure css solution to changing the src-attribute of the logo, unless you want to have two img tags and toggle between the two. This solution just finds the img-tag we want to change, and changes it src attribute to the new url:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("go-home")[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "/images/LOGOWHITE.png";
```

---

An alternate solution is to have two img-tags, one for each version, and toggle them. You can keep your current javascript code, but need to add the following css, and change the html a bit:

```
/* Hide white logo on white background */
body.white .logowhite {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide black logo on non-white (black) background */
body:not(.white) .logoblack {
  display: none;
}
```

```
 <a href="index.html">
   <img class="logoblack" src="images/LOGOBLACK.png">
   <img class="logowhite" src="images/LOGOWHITE.png">
 </a>
```

```js
function togglewhite() {
  if (document.body.classList.contains("white")) {
    console.log("a");
    document.body.classList.remove("white");
  } else {
    console.log("b");
    document.body.classList.add("white");
  }
}
```

```css
/* This is not necessary; it is just for easier viewing what happens */

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.logoblack {
  background: black;
}
.logowhite {
  background: gray;
}
/* This is necessary */

/* Hide white logo on white background */

body.white .logowhite {
  display: none;
}
/* Hide black logo on non-white (black) background */

body:not(.white) .logoblack {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menu" class="hidden">
  <ul>
    <li class="go-home">
      <a href="index.html">
        <img class="logoblack" src="images/LOGOBLACK.png">
        <img class="logowhite" src="images/LOGOWHITE.png">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<input type="button" value="Toggle white" onclick="togglewhite()">
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the first method to sort this out ;)